# (C++) Removing the rows with duplicates in a matrix bug

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, matrix

Remove the rows where a value is encountered twice from the matrix. Where's the bug in my code that I've already written, so that I do it without using any function or anything that would make it easier? 
My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int v[99][99], m, n, i, j, k, vlinie[99], a=0;

    cout<<"m="; cin>>m;
    cout<<"n="; cin>>n;
    for(i=1; i<=m; i++)
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
            cin>>v[i][j];

    //finding out each row that has doubles and remembering its index in an array called vlinie
    for(i=1; i<=m; i++)
        for(j=1; j<=n-1; j++)
            for(k=j+1; k<=n; k++)
                if(v[i][j]==v[i][k])
                    {
                        a++; //a is the number of numbers in vlinie
                        vlinie[a]=i;
                    }

    //removing duplicates from vlinie, in case there are any
    for(i=1; i<=a-1; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<=a; j++)
            if(vlinie[i]==vlinie[j])
                for(k=i; k<=m; k++)
                {
                    vlinie[k]=vlinie[k+1];
                    a--;
                }

    //this is where we move the rows around, and supposedly the line where i got it wrong, so what do i change in this line?
    for(i=1; i<=a; i++)
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
            for(k=vlinie[i]; k<=m; k++)
                v[vlinie[i]+k][j]=v[vlinie[i]+k+1][j];

    for(i=1; i<=m; i++)
        {
            cout<<endl;
            for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
                cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

1 2 2 3
4 5 6 7
7 7 8 9
7 6 5 4

What it should output:

4 5 6 7
7 6 5 4
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 (without the zeros theoretically but the way i wrote it leaves it like this, for now)

What it outputs instead:

1 2 2 3
7 7 8 9
5 4 3 2 (it didn't delete the lines that it should delete and instead deleted some line it should keep)

How do I fix this?

PS: yes, i know i shouldn't have started my indexing at 1 instead of 0, no need to remind me about it again

Comment: I found a first issue: once you find a duplicate in a row, you should stop the search in this line, to avoid incrementing `a` further in this line. However, it is not why your code is not working, as in your example there is only one or zero duplicate per row.

Comment: Oh yea, that would have been an easier way to do it, but it's still not a problem as I got rid of that with the

    for(i=1; i<=a-1; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<=a; j++)
            if(vlinie[i]==vlinie[j])
                for(k=i; k<=m; k++)
                {
                    vlinie[k]=vlinie[k+1];
                    a--;
                }

part

Comment: The indices are not correct in the line where rows are moved. In particular, row `k` must be replaced by row `k+1`. However, code can be simplified by first determining which row will end at position `i`

Comment: "However, code can be simplified by first determining which row will end at position i"
What do you mean? Isn't the row that ends at position i... i?

Comment: I will try to detail it a little bit in an answer. Note: when you address a comment to someone, don't forget to insert @Name in the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was at these lines :

```
   for(i=1; i<=a; i++)
        for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
            for(k=vlinie[i]; k<=m; k++)
                v[vlinie[i]+k][j]=v[vlinie[i]+k+1][j];
```

There is a first issue with the indices: we should copy `v[k+1][]` to `v[k][]`.
The second issue is that once a first move has been performed, the table `vlinie` is no longer valid.
This last point is not so easy to correct.

Moreover, for each suppressed row, you are implementing a shift of several rows, which leads to a poor efficiency.

It is simpler and more efficient to memorize which rows are suppressed (`suppress[]`) and from this table, to determine which row of the input matrix will end at the ith row of the final matrix (table `posi[]`).

Hereafter is an example of implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int v[99][99], m, n, i, j, k, posi[99];
    bool suppress[99];

    std::cout << "m = "; std::cin >> m;
    std::cout << "n = "; std::cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cin >> v[i][j];

    //finding out each row that has doubles
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        suppress[i] = false;
        for (j = 0; (j < n-1) && !suppress[i]; j++)
            for (k = j+1; (k < n) && !suppress[i]; k++)
                suppress[i] =  (v[i][j] == v[i][k]);
    }

    // determination of the moves to be performed
    int n_keep = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (!suppress[i])
            posi[n_keep++] = i;
    }

    //this is where we move the rows around
    for (i = 0; i < n_keep; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                v[i][j] = v[posi[i]][j];

    // Set to 0 remaining rows
    for (i = n_keep; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            v[i][j] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n";
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cout << v[i][j] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does adding ! in front of a variable do, like in " if (!suppress[i])" ? Also in for (j = 0; (j < n-1) && !suppress[i]; j++)

Comment: `suppress[i]` is a boolean, true if the row `i` must be suppressed. So `!suppress[i]` corresponds to the negation, i.e. `true` if the row is *not* suppressed

Comment: why did you put && !suppress[i] at the finding out which row has doubles? The way I read it it would mean you shouldn't stop if the last two elements are doubles and I'm assuming it's not the case considering it doesn't really make sense?

Comment: The loop continue if  `!suppress[i]` is `true`, i.e. if a duplicate has not been found. Conversely, once a duplicate has been found, the loop stopped.